# Clojure: max of list

Tags: clojure

Try to write Clojure program:
Define the function maxim to find the largest element in the list

```
(def boxes [33 11 44 22 66 55])

(println "List of box volumes:" boxes)

(defn top-one [[big1 :as acc] x]
  (cond
    (> x big1) [x big1]
    :else acc))

(defn top-one-list [boxes]
  (reduce top-one [0] boxes))

(println "Biggest volume from boxes:" top-one-list)
    (println "Biggest volume from boxes:" top-one-list)
```

But the output result is:66 44, it print two numbers,who could help me

Comment: why not use `max`? `(defn maxim [xs] (apply max xs))`

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
(> x big1) [x big1]
```

Returns two elements. You only want one.

It should be:

```
(> x big1) [x]
```

A cleaner way to write it would be not to use a list, but only a number as the state of the reduction process:

```
(defn top-one [big1 x]
  (if (> x big1)
    x
    big1))

(defn top-one-list [boxes]
  (reduce top-one 0 boxes))
```

Comment: hi,could you please Write Clojure program which computes

1*1 + 2*2 + … + 100*100.I am new for clojure

Comment: I can, you can as well if you try :-) If you're having trouble show what you've tried by posting it as a question describing the problem and you're research to solve it.

If this answer solved your question you should accept it by checking it.

Comment: hi, I paste the program I try to write to calculate 1*1 + 2*2 + … + 100*100,but it errors, any help

Comment: You should accept this answer if it is helpful, and open a **different**  (new) question.

Answer (score 3):

There are some common classes of data manipulation in clojure. Some would call them patterns though that word was claimed for other purposes a few years ago.

This "patern" is "reduce a bunch of values to a single value"

For these cases, in general, there are a couple approaches:

1. find an existing function in the common or core libraries that already does it.
2. use one of the `reduce` family of functions.

here is an example of each:

First we will solve it with reduce:

```
user> (def boxes [33 11 44 22 66 55])
#'user/boxes

user> (reduce max boxes)
66
```

Reduce maintains two values as it does it's work, first if the answer-thus-far and the second is data that still needs to be included in that answer. It also keeps track of a function who's job it is to take the answer thus var and a new piece of information, and produce the new answer that includes that information. The process stops when the answer includes all the available info. In this case I chose the `max` function as the decision function.

Then by simply using the built in function:

```
user> (apply max boxes)
66
```

`max` may not be an obvious choice because it takes a bunch of discrete arguments, while you wanted to work on a list. This is a common situation and `apply` solves it nicely by building a function call using the collection as the arguments.

```
(apply max [1 2 3])
```

becomes this function call in effect:

```
(max 1 2 3)
```

and max is happy to take even a very large number of arguments efficiently:

```
user> (apply max (range 1e7))
9999999
```